# Rails Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wonder where those controller default actions defined. Even though I do not write the index action, the index view could be render! I used to read rails source code, but I can get where the method declares. I guess the actions is known by rails by the routes.rb . Anyone knows where I can find them in rails source code.

Comment: I suppose you're dealing with a RESTful resource, so Rails recognizes the URL and knows you want to render an index action. Even though you didn't define the index action, convention over configuration wins. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: I need to know how rails deal with this.

Comment: The reason why rails renders the index action without an index action in the controller is because you declared a route matching it (usually `resources :users`) and there is an index template to render.  Without these two, rails will raise an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see in [`rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb#L64-L66)

```
def method_for_action(action_name)
  super || if template_exists?(action_name.to_s, _prefixes)
    "default_render"
  end
end
```

Rails will call default render when there is template even without you define action name.

Comment: I need know where the action is defined rather than the template rendering.

Comment: The action is not defined.
As you can see from the above method body, even if we didn't write index action, as long as we have view template for index, Rails happily render it for us using  `default_render` method.